# ASP.NET MVC localization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to do localization in my ASP.NET MVC project. I need some expert advice that Should I add separate resource file for each model or I should use only one resource file for each Language and In the resource file I need to add all models keys across the project.

like I have 50 models in applications and I want localization for Frech Language so do I need to add only one resource file having keys for all 50 models or should i add separate resource file for each model.

Thanks

Comment: can you give an example of your resources?

Comment: you can have different file for each model with each language. eg: for student, student_fr.resx, student.resx

Comment: You should have different Resource file for different language but one resource file for all models. Create one resource file for one model is not a good approach.

Comment: @coder771 would this approach good ? If you have 50 models and you need to implement 3 languages then it would be 50* 3 = 150 resource files

Comment: @pedram example ... like we have employee, department and so many models like that so while localization do we need to make one resource file for all models or add resource file for each model like 50 model 50 resource files or 1 file having keys for all models... mean each language will have separate resource file but not every model will have separate resource file.

Comment: we had done this few years back. there can be good approach now. we thought then that if it is one file for a language then it would grow too big

Answer (score 0):

I would split file types based on function.

E.g : Have one file for all the display names , another one for all the validation errors.

I would place the files in App_GlobalResources . The advantage with that is that you dont need a new deployment for changes to the resource file .

You can actually create a small console application which can read all your model properties using reflection and put them in a resource file using the resource editor class.